# How to display form using formGroup inside table row in angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

i want to display form inside table row. Each row has factor wise self rating functionality. and user can edit individual factor rating. so i want to display each row has insert functionality later on edit and update as well as.that's why i am using form inside table with in row  but **formGroup** getting error. then after i have used form before table. i got same errors. 
**Here My Error**

```
**Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'**.
```

**Here is my code .html file**

```
`<form [formGroup]="appraisalApplyForm" (ngSubmit)="submitApplyAppraisal()">

                    <table class="table table-bordered" style="overflow-y: auto;">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th class="pdten">Rating Factors</th>
                            <th class="pdten">Self Appraisal Rating </th>
                            <th class="pdten">Supervisor Appraisal Rating</th>
                            <th class="pdten">Justification/Remark</th>
                             <th class="pdten">Action</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                          <ng-container *ngFor="let factor of factors; index as i">

                          <tr  *ngIf="factor.department_id ===parameter.id">

                            <!-- <form method="post" [formGroup]="appraisalApplyForm" (ngSubmit)="submitApplyAppraisal()"> -->
                              <td class="pd_custom  fw " >{{factor.rating_factor_name}}</td>
                              <input type="hidden" formControlName = "department_id" value="{{parameter.id}}"/>
                              <input type="hidden" formControlName = "factor_id" value="{{factor.id}}"/>
                              <td><input class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Rating.."  type="text" formControlName = "self_rating[]"></td>
                              <td><input class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Rating.."  type="text" formControlName = "supervisor_rating[]"></td>
                              <td>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="" placeholder="remark.." formControlName = "remark[]"></textarea>
                              </td>
                              <td><input type="submit" class="btn bg-olive btn-flat margin  " value="submit"></td>
                            <!-- </form> -->

                          </tr>
                        </ng-container>


                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="box-footer">
                      <input type="submit" class="btn bg-olive btn-flat margin  " value="submit">
                  </div>
                  </form>`.
```

**.ts file code**

```
export class AppraisalApplyComponent implements OnInit {
  appraisalApplyForm :FormGroup;
  constructor(private _services: ApiService, private router: Router, private fb: FormBuilder,
    private http: HttpClient) { }

    factors:any;
    parameters:any;

    data = {

    }
  ngOnInit() {

    this.getRatingFactorParameter();
    this.getRatingFactors();
    this.appraisalApplyForm = this.fb.group({
      factor_id: [''],
      department_id: [''],
      self_rating: [''],
      supervisor_rating: [''],
      remark: [''],
      //arr: this.fb.array([])

    });


  }
    submitApplyAppraisal(){
    let route = 'add-apply-appraisal';
    let data = this.appraisalApplyForm.value;
     alert(data);
     return ;
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')?localStorage.getItem('token'):''; 
    console.log(data);
    this._services.requestCreator(data, route, token).subscribe((result: any) => {
      console.log(result.result);
      if (result.status = 200) {
        alert('Rating Factor Data Added Successfully !.');
        console.log("Form Submitted!");
       // this.applyAppraisalForm.reset();
      }
    });
```

**Welcome for Any suggestion for better coding.**

Comment: Did you import ReactiveFormsModule to you module?

Comment: Yea. i have imported this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you cannot use the form inside a table. This will distort the DOM tree.
Secondly, You want that each row has unique functionality. For this, you will have to declare an array of form groups and pass each row data to it.

In your form (ngOnInit) you declared only one form group. I refactor your code. Have a look. Please note that this is not the whole code.

.html file

```
<form [formGroup]="appraisalApplyForm"  class="">
  <div formArrayName="appraisalForm">
    <div
      *ngFor="let appraisalForm of appraisalApplyForm.get('appraisalForm')['controls']; let i = index">
      <form [formGroup]="appraisalForm" (ngSubmit)="submitApplyAppraisal(appraisalForm.value)">
        <tr>
        <td class="pd_custom  fw ">--</td>
        <td><input class="form-control" id="self_rating_{{i}}" placeholder="Enter Rating.."  type="text" formControlName = "self_rating"></td>

        <td><input class="form-control" id="supervisor_rating_{{i}}" placeholder="Enter Rating.."  type="text" formControlName = "supervisor_rating"></td>
        <td>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="remark_{{i}}" placeholder="remark.." formControlName = "remark"></textarea>
        </td>
        <td><input type="submit" class="btn bg-olive btn-flat margin  " value="submit"></td>
        </tr>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

.ts file

```
export class AppraisalApplyComponent  implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
   appraisalApplyForm :FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

    factors:any;
    parameters:any;


    new_factors = [
      {
        department_id: '1',
        rating_factor_name : 'none',
        self_rating : 2,
        supervisor_rating: 3,
        remark: 'Temp'
      },
       {
         department_id: '2',
        rating_factor_name :'none',
        self_rating : 6,
        supervisor_rating: 2,
        remark: 'qwertyuiop'
      },
       {
         department_id: '3',
        rating_factor_name : 'none',
        self_rating : 6,
        supervisor_rating: 9,
        remark: 'asdfghjkl'
      },
    ]

    data = {

    }
    get formArray() { return <FormArray>this.appraisalApplyForm.get('appraisalForm'); }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.appraisalApplyForm = this.fb.group({
       appraisalForm : this.fb.array([])
    });
    this.fill_appraisal_form(this.new_factors);
    console.log(this.appraisalApplyForm);
  }

  addForm() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.appraisalApplyForm.controls['appraisalForm']; 
    control.push(
      this.fb.group({
        factor_id: this.fb.control(''),
        department_id: this.fb.control(''),
        self_rating: this.fb.control(''),
        supervisor_rating: this.fb.control(''),
        remark: this.fb.control(''),
      })
    );
  }

 fill_appraisal_form(form_list) {
    for (let i = 0; i < form_list.length; i++ ) {
      if (this.formArray.length < form_list.length) {
        this.addForm();
      }

      this.formArray.at(i).patchValue({
        department_id: form_list[i].department_id,
        self_rating: form_list[i].self_rating,
        supervisor_rating: form_list[i].supervisor_rating,
        remark: form_list[i].remark
      });
    }
  } 

    submitApplyAppraisal(data){
    let route = 'add-apply-appraisal';
    // let data = this.appraisalApplyForm.value;
     console.log(data);
     return ;
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')?localStorage.getItem('token'):''; 
    console.log(data);
    this._services.requestCreator(data, route, token).subscribe((result: any) => {
      console.log(result.result);
      if (result.status = 200) {
        alert('Rating Factor Data Added Successfully !.');
        console.log("Form Submitted!");
       // this.applyAppraisalForm.reset();
      }
    });
    }
}
```